# Words for musical groups at festivals,carnivals and processions

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I realise there are many words for different musical groups at carnivals,fiestas and processions. I want to write a piece about this music culture in Spain in particular.
The fact is a quick glance online reveals many words to describe them.

Rondallas,Charangas,Comparsas(maybe that is more Latin American),Estudiantinas(university musical groups ,I think),and Chirimbolos.

I am sure there are more in Spain.
What I really want are a few general terms that cover any such events other than words like ''bandas y agrupaciones musicales''.
Can I get some suggestions?
Perhaps, the above are regional.

I know the Semana Santa processions have different terms in that culture, like singing the ''saetas'' during the ''pasos''. Maybe ,they are  simply called ''coros''. I know the ''hermandades'' oversee it all and there are Nazarenos who are not involved in the music.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a term like "fiestas populares"?

Comment: @Gustavson.  No,just I believe there are terms for the individual music  groups and I am looking for a few that cover most events. I think there was one I heard of that starts with  C but I can't remember it.